# Has anyone written a modern editor for Classic ASP?

Tags: ide, asp-classic, editor

I have projects I have to do in Classic ASP.  It would almost be enjoyable if I could get some of the same features that visual studio has, such as intellisense for objects (I know you get some from Visual Studio if you have everything in the same file, but there are quirks with that, as well), or the dropdowns showing functions like Visual Studio.  It would be especially nice if it would recognize include files and use those as well.  It seems to me that enough people are still using it that someone must have written something...

Comment: Just use notepad :)  Or download a copy of Emacs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems to me that enough people are still using it that someone must
>   have written something

You'd think that, but I've been looking for the same thing for a number of years, and even started trying to add the language to Netbeans, but nothing I have found yet matches what you can do in DreamWeaver.

It's a rubbish program that crashes a lot and is far too expensive, but it's about the only option I have found that is any good beyond Visual Studio (2008 or less).

Comment: I've been using Visual Web Developer 2008.  It's been fine, but I really miss the intellisense after developing in .net.   Notepad++ seems pretty good because it gives you some intellisense AND you get macros, apparently not available in the free visual web developer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer sooner.  I created a new account.